# Yii2 model relation

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

When I need to use related data in model, I set the pair of keys (`id_item` and `id`), and the query will be like this -

```
... ON (category.id = category_translate.id_item) ...

public function getTranslate()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CategoryTranslate::className(), 
            ['id_item' => 'id'])->indexBy('language');
    }
```

But what if I need the `ON` part of query be like this - 
`category.left between 1 and 10`.

How Can I do it?

Comment: Use `->leftJoin('category', 'category.left between 1 and 10');`

Answer (score 1):

You should not have a query condition in the ON-part. The ON-part is supposed to link query table to the table you join.

What you actually try to do is, filter your data. But filtering has nothing to do with relations.
So, you should keep your relation as is (maybe even drop the `indexBy('language')` part!) and perform your query like this:

```
$categories = Category::find()
    ->andWhere(['between', 'left', 1, 10])
    ->joinWith('translate')
    ->indexBy('language');
```